# react-native: Android: Building on x86 and testing on ARM

Tags: android, react-native, x86, arm

Running an `ARM` emulator on an `x86` system is extremely slow. I'm building a `react-native` app and wondering how important is it to test on all CPU types or can one confidently test on `x86` and expect `ARM` devices to work well? I understand that there may still be issues related to different Android APIs.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this? I came here while looking for an answer for the same thing

Comment: No answer. Just buy a cheap ARM device :)

Comment: I got mine fixed. See my answer below. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for me. In package details, there is a x86 option. I installed that and it is back to normal. It compiles near a minute sooner and the emulator does not lag whatsoever. See the last checkbox in the picture. I really hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: The question isn't *how* to test on x86, the question is whether that's *sufficient*.  The OP already knows that x86 builds run faster on an x86 host.